How to prevent multiple clicks on the same Interstitial Ad?
Some users of my Android app generate 2-5 clicks for each Ad impression. (Click-through-ratio 200-500% instead of 2-5%).
Sometimes, there are up to 3 clicks in one second, from the same device.
Is it possible to dismiss an Ad as soon as the user clicks it once, so that no invalid clicks are generated?
Is there a publicly available list of IP-addresses associated with invalid activity?
